# What is the best way to create a p2p app in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, p2p

I'd like to know how should I go about creating a p2p app. Is there only 1 way or multiple ways. I would have though that every user would need to create both a server and a connection, or multiple connections to multiple peers. Is this accurate or do I need to be doing something different?

Below is some code I made, the final version would create the server first and then ask for the host:port of a peer to connect to. What I want to know is there a way I can create a p2p app with using only net.createConnection() or another simpler way? Or does every user have to be their own server?

```
const net = require('net')
const readline = require('readline')

const host = 'localhost'
const port = 3000

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if(line == 'server') {
        const server = net.createServer((connection) => {
            console.log('peer connected')
            /**/
            connection.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(data.toString())
            })
            /**/
            rl.on('line', (line) => {
                connection.write('server: ' + line)
            })
            rl.prompt()
            /**/
        }).listen(port)
    }
    else if(line == 'client') {
        const client = net.createConnection(port, host, () => {
            console.log('connected to peer')
            /**/
            client.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(data.toString())
            })
            /**/
            rl.on('line', (line) => {
                client.write('client: ' + line)
            })
            rl.prompt()
            /**/
        })
    }
}).on('close', () => {
    process.exit(0);
})
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [p2p module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p2p).

Comment: I've already seen the p2p module, I don't want to use somebody else's module in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Your code works in a two client scenario but you may have already noticed it is not that easy with more clients.

That's because you need multiple layers/tools:

- An overlay network protocol with address space, so every client gets
  its own address. These addresses will be translated to IP addresses
  by routing tables and that's why it is called overlay network
  protocol. For example if you have 3 bit address space you can have 8
  unique clients. I'd prefer a wide address range where clients
  randomly generate their own ids. [Kademlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) is a good example.
- Now you have solved the addressing and routing problem the next issue
  is if the network is completely p2p then how clients get initial
  route tables and connected. To solve this problem you need some nodes
  with static IPs and high availability which are called bootstrappers.

  Your code do the rest for chatting when two clients can find each
  other by their unique addresses in the app address space. Usually you
  need encryption and a pair of public/private keys. You can you the
  hash of public key as the client unique id.